# Connecting to a programmatically started RMI server over WAN

Tags: java, connection, rmi

I'm trying to connect to a RMI registry that I have started on a remote server, but I get the following exception after a while:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: *.*.*.*; nested exception is:     
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

By running the client localy on the server everything works, but I can't connect to it remotely; Not even from telnet. However, if I run

```
start rmiregistry 1337
```

I can connet to it remotely from telnet. I'm assuming that it's something I have to set up when I'm running the server code, but I have trouble finding out what it is.

This is part of the **server** code:

```
String codeBasePath = "file:/C:/*path*/build/classes";

System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", codeBasePath);
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", *host IP*);

RemoteFileServer server = new FileServer();

Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(PORT);

registry.bind(*name*, server);

System.out.println("Server ready");
```

Let me know if you need more info/code to help me figure it out.

Comment: do you need to set the port property as well, `System.setProperty("java.rmi.activation.port", PORT)`?

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @mre There is no activation in evidence here, ergo no need to set the activation port.

Comment: @EJP Yes, why should that be of importance?
I'm not using the "start registry 1337" and then running the program, because they can't both use the same port.

Comment: It's important because rmiregistry.exe does LocateRegistry.createRegistry() itself. So if you start a registry either way you should be able to Telnet to it either way. So something else must be different. First suspect is the port. Next question is whether you are really getting this exception connecting to the registry or when trying to execute a remote method having already done the lookup(). Next question is whether the address in the exception is the one you can telnet to.

Comment: I understand that rmiregistry.exe does `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`, but since both the program and rmiregistry.exe use the same port it shouldn't make a difference. I get the exception during the lookup from a remote client, and the IP-adress in the exception is the same as the one I'm connecting to. This adress is also the same as I'm using when I connect over telnet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is two options I can think of

1 - Did you give permission for incoming connections with a security policy. This step is quite simple actually see here: [rmi run  tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/running.html)

2 - The port might be closed for outside from OS. For example if you are using linux you need to open the port from iptables like:
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1099 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1099 -j ACCEPT
or if you use windows you can configure it from firewall.

If anything is unclear you can ask.